# MYSQL, using a field created with as in a concat

Tags: mysql, case, concatenation

say I had a table ie

```
___________________
| ID | Name | Job |
+====+======+=====+
| 01 | Fred | br  |
+====+======+=====+
| 02 | Jack | pd  |
+====+======+=====+
```

and I run a query like

```
SELECT 
CASE Job
WHEN 'br' THEN 'cleaner'
WHEN 'pd' THEN 'teacher'
ELSE Job
END as new_job
CONCAT( Name, 'is a', new_job )
FROM table
```

I get an error as I can't use new_job in my concat is there anyway to do this?

Thnaks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it as subquery:

```
 SELECT CONCAT( Name, 'is a', new_job ) FROM(
       SELECT Name, 
          CASE Job
          WHEN 'br' THEN 'cleaner'
          WHEN 'pd' THEN 'teacher'
          ELSE Job
          END as new_job

   FROM table ) sub
```

Comment: You're my new hero! I bet you wear a cape - will accept this answer as soon as I am able. Thankies!

Answer (score 0):

Besides the "wrapping", you can use the `CASE` inside the `CONCAT()` function:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT( Name
          , 'is a'
          , CASE Job
               WHEN 'br' THEN 'cleaner'
               WHEN 'pd' THEN 'teacher'
              ELSE Job
            END 
          ) AS result
FROM table
```